# clone drupal sandbox project into github account with commit history

Tags: github

I have a drupal sandbox project up and running which is being updated by me frquently. But the same is not showing up when I log into my Github account on github.com . Is there a way to integrate both so that whatever changes I push to my drupal sandbox and the commit history also appear on github.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following "[pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3195446/6309)", you could set up your local repo in order to push to *both* upstream repos in one command.

```
[remote "upstreams"]
    url = git@github.com:user/repo.git
    url = your/dropal/sandbox.git
```

Comment: ok so this is the way forward from now onwards, and is there to make my sandhbox past commit history, the multiple revisions that I've done to my code all be available on github too ?

Comment: @geeky_bat the next push should push everything to github. If not, define another remote with just github, in order to push there. In both cases, a push to github will push whatever isn't yet on the  GitHub repo.